# How to avoid response timeout of my webpage in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, timeout, response, execution-time

I'm importing large amount of data from Excel(100.000 rows etc), and get the necessary values from the excel(it took 1 minute approximately)

Then I loop within these records and do some Database insert/update statements. But approximately after 90 seconds the response stops. My page stops but in the background Database goes on and does the insert/update jobs.

But I can't give the user a feedback(your process is complete or such) because the response is ended(timedout).

I try to increase the timeout in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="36000"/>
```

also I try to increase executionTimeout for that specific page like this:

```
<location path="HomePage.aspx"> <!--Excel import takes too long-->
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360000" maxUrlLength="10000" maxQueryStringLength="80000" maxRequestLength="10240" />
  </system.web>  
</location>
```

They didnt work! Any suggestions?

Comment: do a job that inserts that excel and don't do that on page load

Comment: it is not on pageload but in a Linkbutton Event

Comment: then you should start by using a paging system for your data.

Comment: that is not an option for me because the users will import their own data (excel files) and the first step of the application is receiving their Stock to my application

Comment: Have you considered using AJAX for that?

Comment: I have those data in a viewstate, can I use them in AJAX call?

Answer (score 2):

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            **ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).AsyncPostBackTimeout = 6000;**

I increased the AsyncPostBackTimeout to 6000 and this worked for me. My linkbutton(long process) was in an UpdatePanel

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  ...
   <sessionState timeout="90" />
  ...
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

See this

http://asp-net.vexedlogic.com/2012/05/23/aspasp-net-session-timeout-how-do-i-change-it/

http://forums.asp.net/t/1040377.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to work only coupled with the webconfig changes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).AsyncPostBackTimeout = 6000;
}
```

Without this it didn't work for me.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="36000" />
```